# Node js v5.9.1 and class 'import/export' statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have installed official node js version v5.9.1 (x64) on windows, and tried to do some work with classes using ECMAScript. I wrote a simple class to test:

```
"use strict";

export class httpWrapper {

    getPage(options){

      // some code

    }



};
```

And i put this class in the `httpWrapper.js`. As you can see im using export here to export the class. Then i created 'main.js' with this code:

```
'use strict';


import httpWrapper from 'httpWrapper';  
let theInstance = new httpWrapper();
```

When i run `node main.js` i get the error:

```
import httpWrapper from 'httpWrapper';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:142:18)
    at node.js:939:3
```

I also tried to run `httpWrapper.js` with node and i got:

```
export class httpWrapper {
^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
        at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
        at startup (node.js:142:18)
        at node.js:939:3
```

Does the import/export features avaliable in node js? Because those statement doesn't work, i cannot use export/import, how do you suppose to export/import classes?

Comment: No, it doesn't for now

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/NG/issues/5 there's an ongoing discussion

Answer (score 0):

Right now browsers does not understand the ES6(ECMAScript2015) you need to use a transpiler like babel that converts ES6 to ES5.

Answer (score -1):

you need install `npm install babel-cli -g` , then run `babel-node main.js` or if u need run with node, needs create js with require hook babel-register.
Example:

```
// runner.js 
// I implement async in my modules, for this reason i need the preset stage-3 & es2015-node to support es6 features
require("babel-register")({
  presets: ['es2015-node', 'stage-3']
});

// Import you main module with require and run
// On this example I export http.createServer on server.js -> export default server

var server = require('./server.js')

server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server running')
})

// Server.js 
import express from 'express'
import { Server } from 'http'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import morgan from 'morgan'

var app = express()

// configuracion
app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.set('view engine', 'jade')

// Route para nuestra API
var router = express.Router()

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' })
})

app.use('/api', router)

var server = Server(app) // require('http').createServer(app.callback())
// app.listen(3000)

console.log('Magic happens on port 3000')
export default server
```

Now only run `node runner.js` sometimes needs add the flag --harmony

Comment: If you needs use ES6 on Browsers, I recommend Babel Transpilers: Webpack + Babel-loader or Gulp + gulp-babel.